# Why does my spawned thread open in the parent AppDomain instead of the current child AppDomain?

Tags: multithreading, appdomain

We have a service that runs multiple (and varied, depending on pieces installed) assembly modules.  Each module is run in its own AppDomain because we can have multiple instances of the same assembly running, connected to different databases.

Recently I added a new module, to replace an existing, separate service.  This module is multi-threaded and also uses our inhouse, legacy logging library which is also multi-threaded.  The new module is a c# wrapper over existing unmanaged c++ code.

My problem is that the logging code stores data in the AppDomain, including the file name and location to write to, etc.  This works fine on the module's main thread, but when new threads are created they are created under the parent AppDomain, that of the service executable itself.  The parent AppDomain doesn't contain the data the logging code is looking for and so it can't write out its data.

I found an article about this stating that threads created using the old Win32 CreateThread() call would not be created in the current AppDomain and that I should use .Net threads.  That was the case with my code, so I changed my module code to use .Net threads and I am still getting the same result.

I also tried making the logging class run as a Singleton, but the spawned threads still try to pull the Singleton from the parent AppDomain, which of course doesn't have the correct data.

I really need to get this working and I have hit a wall.

Any ideas???

Comment: Don't add signature. Visit FAQ.

Comment: Nothing to look at.  "Wrapper over existing unmanaged c++ code" is a Big Red Flag, app domains are a pure managed code concept and does not apply to unmanaged code.

Comment: To clarify: the c++ code was originally written as unmanaged, but is currently compiled as CLR and now uses .net Thread objects instead of calling Win32 ::CreateThread().